# jQuery: script for delaying removeClass() delays too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a grid of products. Some products have *gifts* "attached".

```js
$('.icon').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.product-box').addClass("hovered");
}, function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).closest('.product-box').removeClass("hovered");
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.product-box {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
.product-box .icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 7px;
}
.product-box h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
.product-box .price {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.product-box .gift {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 101%;
  z-index: 99;
  display: none;
}
.product-box .gift p {
  margin: 0;
}
.product-box .gift img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.product-box.hovered .gift {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="product-box">
      <h3 class="product-name text-center">Lorem</h3>
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/200/200" />
      </div>
      <div class="price text-center">$100</div>
      <div class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Add to cart</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="product-box">
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <div class="gift">
        <p>Gift</p>
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" />
      </div>
      <h3 class="product-name text-center">Lorem</h3>
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/200/200" />
      </div>
      <div class="price text-center">$100</div>
      <div class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Add to cart</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="product-box">
      <h3 class="product-name text-center">Lorem</h3>
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/200/200" />
      </div>
      <div class="price text-center">$100</div>
      <div class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Add to cart</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

When I hover over the gift icon, a box with the gift details appears as the product box is added the class "hovered" from jQuery.

With no help from jQuery, if the user wants to click the *gift* box, it does not stay long enough to be cliked.

So I have tried to add a *delay* to the removal of the class "hovered" with the help of the `setTimeout()` function.

There are 2 problems:

1. The gift box does not disappear on mouseout.
2. The gift box should stay as long as *it* is hovered.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You change the scope with the timeout function so `this` is not the same `this` from the mouseout function - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem with `this` in your `setTimeout` callback

```
$('.icon').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.product-box').addClass("hovered");
}, function() {
  var self = this; // create variable that holds `this` reference from this scope
  setTimeout(function() {
    // use self instead of this
    $(self).closest('.product-box').removeClass("hovered");
  }, 1000);
});
```

```js
$('.icon').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.product-box').addClass("hovered");
}, function() {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(self).closest('.product-box').removeClass("hovered");
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.product-box {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
.product-box .icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 7px;
}
.product-box h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
.product-box .price {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.product-box .gift {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 101%;
  z-index: 99;
  display: none;
}
.product-box .gift p {
  margin: 0;
}
.product-box .gift img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.product-box.hovered .gift {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="product-box">
      <h3 class="product-name text-center">Lorem</h3>
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/200/200" />
      </div>
      <div class="price text-center">$100</div>
      <div class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Add to cart</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="product-box">
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <div class="gift">
        <p>Gift</p>
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" />
      </div>
      <h3 class="product-name text-center">Lorem</h3>
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/200/200" />
      </div>
      <div class="price text-center">$100</div>
      <div class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Add to cart</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="product-box">
      <h3 class="product-name text-center">Lorem</h3>
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/200/200" />
      </div>
      <div class="price text-center">$100</div>
      <div class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Add to cart</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It must stay if the gift box is hovered.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.icon').hover(function() {
  let productBox = $(this).closest('.product-box');
  productBox.addClass("hovered");
}, function() {
  let productBox = $(this).closest('.product-box');
  setTimeout(function() { 
    productBox.removeClass("hovered");
  }, 1000);
});
```